# Looking for a web tool for core dump/crash dump analysis

Tags: web-apps, software-development, c++, debugging

Our team needs to analyse core dumps from testers (or sometimes from clients) that C++ libraries and applications produce. Both on Windows & Linux. Of course we can use `gdb` to analyse it, but it is all about simplifying and team-work. Do you know any Atlassian, Jetbrains or others web tool or plugin that can integrate with Jenkins or BitBucket for example, that simplifies (browse a stack trace and a list of local variables, etc.) C++ core dump analysis?

Comment: IMHO your request is too broad, covering Windows + Linux + User mode + Kernel mode. There once was a tool for Windows only, called [Instant Online Crash Analysis](http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm%5Ename=Analyze.htm). However, it was for Windows only and with very limited functionality (running `!analyze -v`). Also, the terms of use were not exactly great. They reserved the right to use the uploaded crash dump in seminars. Crash dumps may contain personal information, they definitely contain information about the system of the user and may even contain passwords. That's quite sensitive data.

Comment: Also, Microsoft once provided online crash dump analysis, also for Windows only. It was a service called Windows Error Reporting (WER), then renamed to Windows Quality Online Services (WinQual). Both services do not exist any more. As the [top all time WinDbg user](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/windbg/topusers), I don't know any online service and my guess is that you have to write your own. Be prepared that people upload files that are 4 GB large, just to find out that they ran into a OutOfMemory condition.

Comment: An online service also has the problem of finding the matching PDBs. If you don't upload them as well, the reliable information will be limited. I think that's the main reason that online tools do not exist. If you do it yourself, consider linking the analysis tool to your symbol store (e.g. TFS).

Comment: All in all +1. I think the request for such a tool is valid. If you develop one, ping me. I'd be glad trying it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know gdb, why not automate it?

Everyone seems to know Python these days, so take a look at these (or choose your own way to automate it):

- [Invoke and control GDB from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482869/invoke-and-control-gdb-from-python)
- [Extending GDB using Python](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html) - with a link to the API to control gdb from Python
- [scripting gdb](http://tromey.com/blog/?p=548)
- [pygdbmi](https://pypi.org/project/pygdbmi/) - "A function to parse gdb machine interface string output and return structured data types (Python dicts) that are JSON serializable."

Comment: Of course I can write my own plugin/script. But there are different compilers on different OS'es so that I am asking for ready solution. If it doesn't exist, I could give my time and write it :)

Comment: I hope that you don't have to, as I would also like to have such a tool :-)  It seems that I spend more time these days writing Python scripts than doing "real coding" :-)